# WCF RIA service

Tags: wcf

having the following issue with newly created RIA service:

```
system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.Domainoperationexception: 
load operation failed for query 'GetUser'.
```

Why did the project automatically inlude the `UserRegistrationContext` service anyway? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue many times and there are so many reasons for the same.
Secondly as soon as you create RIA service, VS automatically generate the proxy code in SL application. You can find the proxy code under generatedcode folder in your solution.